# Comparing array of strings and display the result when matched to Out-GridView?

Tags: powershell

How can I get the result so the user email address that already listed in the AllowedSenderDomains is displayed in UserEmailDomainAlreadyRegistered array so I can output to OGV?

```
$UserEmailDomainAlreadyRegistered = # If the user email domain is found in the $AllowedSenderDomains, then display it in OGV

$AllowedSenders = @('User.Name@domain.com', 'User2.Name2@domain.net', 'User3.Name3@domain.net','unique.user@email.com')
    
$AllowedSenderDomains = @('domain.net', 'domain.com')
```

The expected result fo the above is:

```
'User.Name@domain.com'
'User2.Name2@domain.net'
'User3.Name3@domain.net'
```

**Updated Code:**

```
$policyName = '*'
$policy = Get-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity $PolicyName

$AllowedSenderDomains = $Policy.'AllowedSenderDomains' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Domain -Unique
$AllowedSenders = $Policy.'AllowedSenders' | Select-Object Sender

$allowedDomains = '@({0})$' -f (($AllowedSenderDomains | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')
$AllowedSenders | Where-Object { $_ -match $allowedDomains } | OGV

$AllowedSenders | Where-Object { $AllowedSenderDomains -contains ($_ -split '@')[-1] } | OGV
```

Both of the OGV above shows empty content?

```
$AllowedSenderDomains
Domain1.com
Domain2.net
Domain3.org

$AllowedSenders
User1@domain1.com
User2@domain2.net
User3@Domain3.org
```

Comment: Can you show anything you’ve tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach can be to use regex, although with just two allowed domains this is probably overkill:

```
$AllowedSenderDomains = 'domain.net', 'domain.com'
$AllowedSenders       = 'User.Name@domain.com', 'User2.Name2@domain.net', 'User3.Name3@domain.net','unique.user@email.com'

# create a regex from the allowed domains by joining them with OR (|)
# the regex is preceeded by the AT sign (@) and anchored to the end of the string with '$'
$allowedDomains = '@({0})$' -f (($AllowedSenderDomains | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|')
# next, use -match to get only the emailaddresses that match the regex
$AllowedSenders | Where-Object { $_ -match $allowedDomains }
```

You could also use `-split` as another alternative like this:

```
$AllowedSenders | Where-Object { $AllowedSenderDomains -contains ($_ -split '@')[-1] }
```

Result

```
User.Name@domain.com
User2.Name2@domain.net
User3.Name3@domain.net
```

Comment: thank you for the great suggestion when I incorporate your suggestion into the code, it does not show anything as the result?
See the above-updated code in the question.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I think you missed `-ExpandProperty Sender` on `$AllowedSenders`, because there you also want a string array to compare against

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `where-object` commandlet to filter out the domains you don't want:

```
# ~> $AllowedSenders | Where-Object { $_.Substring($_.LastIndexOf('@')+1) -in $AllowedSenderDomains}
User.Name@domain.com
User2.Name2@domain.net
User3.Name3@domain.net
```

Comment: Thanks @zdan, it throws error:
Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'LastIndexOf'.
At line:1 char:34
+ ... re-Object { $_.Substring($_.LastIndexOf('@')+1) -in $AllowedSenderDom ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (LastIndexOf:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer That's because you're not passing string objects down the pipeline. You don't say where the objects are coming from, your example only has strings. What is the name of the property that holds the allowed senders?